# windows 10 upgrade wont show percentages or time remaining

Tags: windows-7, windows, upgrade, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

My dad is using windows 7 professional 64 - bit and he has clicked that upgrade to windows 10 button in the notification area but it has been going on for an hour and a half without any percentage sign or time remaining to tell what's donwloaded and what's not.

We can't tell if it will be done in an hour later or it has failed.

It keeps saying "Starting upgrading" and the internet connection is well persistent.

What could cause this issue?
What other upgrading methods can be used without the need of him to reformat his hdd .. (As this can be done but he is very against it..)

**edit**

So @megamorf in the comments suggested i can find a list of downloaded files in `C:\Windows~BT` folder which I did.

But a huge question here, In `C:\Windows~BT` folder "Date modified" is set to yesterday's date.

Yes, we tried this yesterday on a slow connection. But why it doens't show the whole today long & big update files? (Or at least proves it in the date modified filed ?)

Comment: Is the WIndows 7 machine still usable? (Explorer, Task Manager) If so he can have a look at the root of C:\ there should be a hidden folder ($Windows.~BT or $Windows.~WS) where the Windows 10 files being downloaded to. It should be several GBs in size. If that isn't the case I guess it's currently downloading the rest of the setup files.

Comment: That's a good point! Yes i see the file, it's 2.7 Gb in size and it's a C:\$Windows.~BT folder. But the only thing is we cancelled the running one, went to microsoft site and donwloaded a new **installer** so now another download is running and i just hope it will only download the files left. @megamorf

Comment: Is the New installer running better now? and you can actually maybe see some progress? are you still on the slow connection or are you trying a different connection now?

Comment: The new installer is still running without any sign or percentages or remaining time. Today we have been on the best connection. Also just now it changed the "Date modified" field to today with "time" set to the time he started today's first upgrade. High hopes now.. :) @NetworkKingPin

Comment: Sounds like its going well now! Glad you got it fixed.